# Image Picker - null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller, uiwebviewdelegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image, 0.5);
[_webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
}
```

In this line i am having null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument warning. Any idea to fix this issue?

```
[_webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Is one of the parameter nil? What's the whole error message?

Comment: loadData part is giving me this warning. @Larme

Comment: Is `imageData` nil?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the interface for UIWebView. None of the parameters in that method are marked as nullable, therefore passing nil for baseURL is causing that warning.

Although, I'm guessing it is supposed to be marked as nullable and it's an error on Apple's part.